# WPF MVVM Validation Using IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a Person MVVM model which needs to be validated. I am using IDataErrorInfo class and validating the user. But when the screen loads the textboxes are already red/validated indicating that the field needs to be filled out. I believe this is because I bind the PersonViewModel in the InitializeComponent. I tried to use LostFocus for updatetriggers but that did not do anything.

Here is my PersonViewModel:

```
 public class PersonViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName; 

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; }
        }



        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string validationResult = String.Empty; 

                switch(columnName)
                {
                    case "FirstName":
                        validationResult = ValidateFirstName();
                        break; 

                    case "LastName":
                        validationResult = ValidateLastName();
                        break; 

                    default:
                        throw new ApplicationException("Unknown property being validated on the Product");
                }

                return validationResult; 
            }
        }

        private string ValidateLastName()
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) ? "Last Name cannot be empty" : String.Empty;
        }

        private string ValidateFirstName()
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ? "First Name cannot be empty" : String.Empty;
        }



    }
```

Here is the XAML:

```
  <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>First Name</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Background="Gray"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock>Last Name</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Background="Gray"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            _personViewModel = new PersonViewModel();

            this.DataContext = _personViewModel; 



        }
```

Am I missing something? I do not want the validation to be fired when the screen loads. I only want it to be fired when the user looses the focus of the textboxes.

Comment: Did you try changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus`

Comment: Yes, I updated it to LostFocus and that did not do anything.

Comment: Your "Error" property getter throws an exception -- that could be a problem?

Comment: I am now returning String.Empty from Error property and still the same issue.

Comment: @McGarnagle: WPF doesn't use Error, it is legacy from WinForms, I believe.

Comment: @johndoe Regarding INotifyPropertyChanged it doesn't help in this specific scenario, I was just saying if you ever want the View to pick up changes in your ViewModel then you should implement it in your ViewModel. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @johndoe Why would you not want a user to initially see what is required on the form?

Comment: @johndoe: There are many cases where you wouldn't want that. Say you have a screen that allows you to add, but not edit objects. Once saved, these objects may change and following other validation rules that do not concern this view. But they are still valid none-the-less. For required fields, not so much of course. But generalizing it a bit, there is no need to perform (potentially expensive) validations on data that is already persisted.

Comment: @EricScherrer Hmm interesting! I never thought about it this way. I believe I just need to change the way the ErrorTemplate is being displayed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop IDataErrorInfo from firing for new items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231239/how-can-i-stop-idataerrorinfo-from-firing-for-new-items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than fight the tide of how WPF works by default, consider redefining the UI so that the error display 'fits' the scenario of screen load as well as data entry error. Besides, a user should have some hints on a blank form of what is needed.

Comment: Leaving it as-is is absolutely fine for 'Required' type validation. But consider caching validation results as soon as they get more expensive to do (e.g. you need to touch a database or similar)

Answer (score 2):

Create a method to do your validation, and store the validation results in a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public void Validate(string propertyName)
{
    string validationResult = null;
    switch(propertyName)
    {
        case "FirstName":
            validationResult = ValidateFirstName();
            break; 
        }
        //etc.
    }

    //Clear dictionary properly here instead (You must also handle when a value becomes valid again)
    _validationResults[propertyName] = validationResult;
    //Note that in order for WPF to catch this update, you may need to raise the PropertyChanged event if you aren't doing so in the constructor (AFTER validating)
}
```

Then update your ViewModel to:

1. Have the indexer return a result from the _validationErrors instead, if present.
2. Call Validate() in your setters.
3. Optionally, in Validate(), if the propertyName is null, validate all properties.

WPF will call the indexer to display errors, and since you are returning something, it will think that there are errors. It won't unless you explictly call Validate() with this solution.

EDIT: Please also note that there is now a more efficient way of implementing validation in .NET 4.5 called [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I can create a ValidationEngine Framework for this but I really need to find a decent solution using DataBinding in WPF.

Comment: This *is* using DataBinding. WPF will bind to your indexer, and see that it returns a non-null, non-empty string. This is the only way WPF has to determine whether or not the property is valid. Also, calling a locally stored dictionary (which is a good idea for performance anyway) a Framework is a bit over the top.